# Issue generating dynamically a batch in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I'm trying to execute a dynamic SQL statement that requires the implementation of a batch with a table already created. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testComputed
(
    a int NULL,
    b int NULL
)

DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)
SET @statement = CONCAT(char(13), 'ALTER TABLE testcomputed ADD c int NULL;', char(13), char(10), 'GO', char(13), char(10), 'ALTER TABLE testcomputed ADD e AS (c + 1);')

PRINT @statement

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

But if I copy and execute the print result, this works without any problem ...

If I remove the `GO` from the statement, then I will get this other error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line ##
> Invalid column name 'c'

What could be missing here, how can I handle this?

Comment: `GO` is not a SQL keyword (it's the batch separator used by SSMS) - just remove it from your statement.

Comment: GO is not a SQL keyword. It's a batch separator used by the SQL Server Management Studio code editor tool for when more than one SQL Statement is entered in the Query window. Just remove it.

Comment: Thanks @Stu and JNevill for your anwser. I have updated the post.

Comment: @d2907 Execute each statement separately. Really there is no reason for all of this concatenation and dynamic sql. Just two alter statements should do the job.

Comment: That's because both statements are being parsed in a *single batch* - at compile time column `c` doesn't exist; execute them as 2 statements, although why use dynamic SQL here?

Comment: It is part of the process. We need to parse the information of the table from a JSON file, create it and generate one single row for each table created.

Answer (score 0):

`GO` is not a T-SQL command. It's a batch separator used in SSMS and sqlcmd to separate batches. In dynamic SQL, you can just use separate batches

```sql
CREATE TABLE testComputed
(
    a int NULL,
    b int NULL
)

DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max) = '
ALTER TABLE testcomputed
  ADD c int NULL;
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement;

SET @statement = '
ALTER TABLE testcomputed
  ADD e AS (c + 1);
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d34bf765ce14ce8a29814731732610bd)

In this particular instance, you don't actually need dynamic SQL.

If you are creating and altering the table in one batch then you can rely on [deferred name resolution](https://littlekendra.com/2021/10/18/deferred-name-resolution-in-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-functions/).

```sql
CREATE TABLE testComputed
(
    a int NULL,
    b int NULL
);
ALTER TABLE testcomputed ADD c int NULL;
ALTER TABLE testcomputed ADD e AS (c + 1);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f7fba04bbf9b1de0818726fd7a17d84e)

Or better, even in a batch which cannot rely on deferred name resolution, you can add both columns at once

```sql
CREATE TABLE testComputed
(
    a int NULL,
    b int NULL
);
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE testcomputed
  ADD c int NULL,
      e AS (c + 1);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b575fde605333e4d6a362d0974cf564a)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. My issue is that the table can be updated by the user throught a JSON file  and, I need to parse that definition and provide just one single execution status. If there is one error in the description of the columns in the JSON, I will reject the entire creation/update statement. That is why I was trying to implement one single dynamic sql command. But now I understand that this is not possible.

Comment: I suggest you put that into a new question, showing what you are *actually* trying to do. You should still be able to combine the two, using `STRING_AGG`. Alternatively, do the whole thing in a transaction, and it will roll back if there is an error